# Draw arc through three point opencv

Tags: emgucv

I have three Point A(a1,a2) , B (b1, b2) , C (c1, c2). How to draw arc through three point and calculate arc angle.

Thanks all.

[HERE] http://photo.ssc.vn/view.php?filename=374df.png

Comment: What kind of arc? Circle? Quadratic? Cubic spline?

Comment: Circle. But I just wanted to get an arc through 3 points there. see picture for more details. Thank you

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/drawing_functions.html

Comment: If you have and code samples that arent working, dont be afraid to post them

Comment: I drawed circle. But it is not like purpose of me

Comment: Do you want to draw one like this http://www.mathopenref.com/const3pointcircle.html

Comment: The picture you posted looks more like a spline (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics))

Comment: Also what is "arc angle"?

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you choose a quadratic you will have

y = ax*x + bx + c

Three points A(x1, y1)    B(x2, y2)   C(x3, y3)

This gives a Linear system

y1 = ax1*x + bx1 + c

y2 = ax2*x + bx2 + c

y3 = ax3*x + bx3 + c

Which can be solved for a, b and c

In the event that you are using a circle, use

```
Emgu.CV.PointCollection.MinEnclosingCircle
```

This will give you an object of type CircleF, which has a property Center of type PointF.

Find the vectors between the points and the center.

Va = A - Center

Vb = B - Center

Vc = C - Center

Find the angles between these vectors. You are looking for the largest acute angle. 
You can use dot product to calculate the angle.

Comment: How to i calculate arc angle.